# How to make collapse uncollapse entire row not only plus icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the entire row when I click to collapse uncollapse, because now I have only when I click plus/minus icon I want to be able when I click anywhere on row to collapse/uncollapse.

```html
 <link href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
 <div class="box box-default collapsed-box box-solid">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Expandable</h3>

                  <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-tools -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  The body of the box
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
              </div>
                     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
              
                 <script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

Make full snipet and you can see only when you click to the right corner, which is supposed to be a plus sign but I don't know why it is not showing here, any way can someone help me how can I make when I click  box-header to collapse/uncollapse

Answer (score 0):

Give the data-widget="collapse" to the header container like this:

```
<div class="box box-default collapsed-box box-solid">
                <div class="box-header with-border" data-widget="collapse">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Expandable</h3>

                  <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-tools -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                  The body of the box
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
              </div>
```

Comment: When I did that the icon plus states plus its not changing to minus